# To which FB API does FB C# SDK makes calls?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I want to know that, to which **version of the FB API** does **FB C# SDK** makes calls, as V1.0 FB API is soon going to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply by the developer on twitter post:

https://twitter.com/PrabirShrestha/status/570646448854794240

According to him V6.0 and above of FB C# SDK will be sending unversioned calls to FB if it’s not defined.